# why does the code instantiate the hashset using smaller list?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am checking to see the org.apache.commons.collections4.ListUtils class and noticed the code is as below:

```
public static <e> List<e> intersection(final List<? extends E> list1, final List<? extends E> list2) {
        final List<e> result = new ArrayList<>();

        List<? extends E> smaller = list1;
        List<? extends E> larger = list2;
        if (list1.size() > list2.size()) {
            smaller = list2;
            larger = list1;
        }

        final HashSet<e> hashSet = new HashSet<>(smaller);

        for (final E e : larger) {
            if (hashSet.contains(e)) {
                result.add(e);
                hashSet.remove(e);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

do we know why they turn the smaller list to the hash set and loop the bigger list? thanks.

Comment: It's faster and uses less memory than the other way around. Imagine if one list has 3 items and the other has 3 million.

Comment: @tzaman, Thanks for your replying. I understand it uses less memory, but why is it faster? Will it be looping 3 million times in your example?

Comment: It has to loop 3 million times either way; either to put entries into the HashSet or to check against it. Naturally checking is faster than adding.

Comment: @tzaman, I see. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say the smaller list has `M` entries, the larger list has `N` entries and that the Set gives you constant time access for the basic operations (add, contains).

If I classify this algorith with Big O notation the runtime would be `O(M+N)` and additional memory consumption `O(M)`.

2 observations if we switch the smaller with the larger list:

- The additional memory usage will increase to `O(N)`, so that's one reason not to do it this way.
- On paper the runtime wouldn't change, still `O(M+N)`, but in practice creating a Set of `N` entries, will be a more heavy-weight operation than iterating over it.

If you want to verify these assumptions try [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) which is a tool to run microbenchmarks in Java.

I ran an unscientific benchmark of this with `M=1000`, `N=10000`. This is what I got:

```
Benchmark               (size)  Mode  Cnt       Score      Error  Units
IntersectBench.larger    10000  avgt    5  190481.075 ± 6488.649  ns/op
IntersectBench.smaller   10000  avgt    5  125997.594 ± 1616.975  ns/op
```

The interesting value is in `Score`, smaller is better here. `IntersectBench.smaller` is the same algorithm as above, `IntersectBench.larger` is the algorithm where the lists are swapped and the optimization of swapping them is removed. As you can see the unoptimized version is 50% slower.